# Ruby on Rails: Using Foreign Key twice in the same table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

I have two models:

```
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :g_words, class_name: 'Translation', foreign_key: 'g_id'
  has_many :v_words, class_name: 'Translation', foreign_key: 'v_id'
end

class Translation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :g, class_name: 'Word', required: true
  belongs_to :v, class_name: 'Word', required: true
end
```

**Table Translations**

```
t.text "note", limit: 65535
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "g_id"
t.integer  "v_id"
```

In table **Words** I already inserted 2 values:

```
id     body
1      Home
2      Maison
```

When I create a new Translation with

```
g_id     v_id
1        2
```

Then the following error appears. [image]

The search a lot on the internet about my problem and here is a post about what I want to achieve exactly: http://www.emreakkas.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-multiple-columns-to-the-same-tables-key

I tried to implemented and failed.

I don't know whether I implented the associations wrong or I declared the wrong foreign Keys. I really don't know where to start finding the error. I hope you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't use the snippets feature for Ruby or just arbitrary code. Its for creating runnable JS/CSS/HTML examples. Also you should include the relevant portions of the error message as text in the question body as text. Respond by editing the answer - not by commenting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to build a translations table this is how you would do it:

```
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations
  has_many :languages, through: :translations
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations
  has_many :words, through: :translations
end

class Translation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :word
end
```

But Rails already has [a built in i18n API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) which handles translations that you should take a look at first before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But I think you got mw wrong. I want to use the same foreign from table WORDS twice in table TRANSLATIONS.

Comment: *foreign key @max

Comment: Your whole DB design is backwards. Using the same key won't fix the problem.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to achieve: http://www.emreakkas.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-multiple-columns-to-the-same-tables-key

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max could you have a look again please. Thank you